# Sparql exists function not working with bind if

Tags: if-statement, sparql, bind, exists, virtuoso

My Virtuoso is (`virtuoso-t -h`):

```
Virtuoso Open Source Edition (Column Store) (multi threaded)
Version 7.2.4.2.3217-pthreads as of Jun  3 2016
Compiled for Linux (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

The Sparql function `exists` is working fine, but not when combined with `(bind if(...))`.
The query:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT  ?uri  ?popEstimate ?existsPopEstim ?usedExPop
WHERE {
    ?uri  a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Place>.

    {?uri rdfs:label "France"@fr}
    UNION {?uri rdfs:label "Brésil"@fr}
    UNION {?uri rdfs:label "Amérique"@fr}

    OPTIONAL {?uri dbo:populationEstimate ?popEstimate .}   
    BIND (exists{?uri dbo:populationEstimate ?popEstimate} AS ?existsPopEstim )
    BIND (IF(?existsPopEstim , "ok", "no") AS ?usedExPop)
}
LIMIT 100
```

The result:

```
uri                                  | popEstimate | existsPopEstim | usedExPop
-------------------------------------+-------------+----------------+----------
http://dbpedia.org/resource/France   |             | 0              | ok
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Brazil   | 201032714   | 1              | ok
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Americas |             | 0              | ok
```

**Edit 1**

The example from @AKSW answer, which is also not working on https://dbpedia.org/sparql:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT *
WHERE {
    ?uri a dbo:SoccerPlayer
    OPTIONAL {?uri dbo:deathDate ?date}
    BIND (exists{?uri dbo:deathDate ?date} AS ?existsProp )
    BIND (IF(?existsProp , "ok", "no") AS ?usedExProp) }
LIMIT 1000
```

**Edit 2**
Example on dbpedia:
http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+xsd%3A+%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2009%2FXMLSchema%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+rdfs%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT++%3Furi++%3Fpop+%3FexistsPop+%3FusedExPop%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%09%3Furi++a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPlace%3E.%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%7B%3Furi+rdfs%3Alabel+%22France%22%40en%7D%0D%0A%09UNION+%7B%3Furi+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Brazil%22%40en%7D%0D%0A%09UNION+%7B%3Furi+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Raging+River%22%40en%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%3Furi+dbo%3ApopulationTotal+%3Fpop+.%7D%09%0D%0A%09BIND+%28exists%7B%3Furi+dbo%3ApopulationTotal+%3Fpop%7D+AS+%3FexistsPop%29%0D%0A%09BIND+%28IF%28%3FexistsPop%2C+%22ok%22%2C+%22no%22%29+AS+%3FusedExPop%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+1000&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=3000000&run=+Run+Query+

Comment: Should be a bug according to your example. You should report it on the Virtuoso mailing list. Nobody here can do anything else.

Comment: Minor comments: Use SPARQL 1.1 `VALUES` and be careful with the prefixes. Adapted query: `PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT  *
WHERE {
    VALUES ?label {"France"@fr "Brésil"@fr "Amérique"@fr}
    ?uri a dbo:Place ;
         rdfs:label ?label
    OPTIONAL {?uri dbp:populationEstimate ?popEstimate}   
    BIND (exists{?uri dbp:populationEstimate ?popEstimate} AS ?existsPopEstim )
    BIND (IF(?existsPopEstim , "ok", "no") AS ?usedExPop)
    
}
LIMIT 100`

Comment: Can also be reproduced on the public DBpedia endpoint: `SELECT  *
WHERE {
    
    ?uri a dbo:SoccerPlayer 
        
    OPTIONAL {?uri dbo:deathDate ?date}   
    BIND (exists{?uri dbo:deathDate ?date} AS ?existsProp )
    BIND (IF(?existsProp , "ok", "no") AS ?usedExProp)   
}` It always returns "no", except for the first row: `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fritz_Walter 
2002-06-17
1
ok`

Comment: Thanks for your answers @AKSW. I added your last example which is showing well that the problem is real and is on the side of Virtuoso

Comment: @Niii, [`bound`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-bound) works fine on DBpedia: try `BIND (bound(?pop) AS ?exists1Pop) .
BIND (IF(?exists1Pop , "ok", "no") AS ?usedEx1Pop)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you are experiencing this problem via Version 7.2.4.2.3217-pthreads as of Jun  3 2016. Here's what happens with the more recent 7.2.x and 8.0 releases via live example links:

- [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT++%3Furi++%3FpopEstimate+%3FexistsPopEstim+%3FusedExPop%0D%0A%23+FROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%3E+%0D%0AWHERE+%7B%0D%0A%09%3Furi++a+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPlace%3E.%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%7B%3Furi+rdfs%3Alabel+%22France%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09UNION+%7B%3Furi+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Br%C3%A9sil%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09UNION+%7B%3Furi+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Am%C3%A9rique%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL+%7B%3Furi+dbo%3ApopulationEstimate+%3FpopEstimate+.%7D%09%0D%0A%09BIND+%28exists%7B%3Furi+dbo%3ApopulationEstimate+%3FpopEstimate%7D+AS+%3FexistsPopEstim+%29%0D%0A%09BIND+%28IF%28%3FexistsPopEstim+%2C+%22ok%22%2C+%22no%22%29+AS+%3FusedExPop%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT+100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+) -- running 7.2.x (2017 release)
- [URIBurner](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%20%3Furi%20%20%3FpopEstimate%20%3FexistsPopEstim%20%3FusedExPop%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%09%3Furi%20%20a%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPlace%3E.%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%7B%3Furi%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22France%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09UNION%20%7B%3Furi%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Br%C3%A9sil%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09UNION%20%7B%3Furi%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Am%C3%A9rique%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Furi%20dbo%3ApopulationEstimate%20%3FpopEstimate%20.%7D%09%0D%0A%09BIND%20%28exists%7B%3Furi%20dbo%3ApopulationEstimate%20%3FpopEstimate%7D%20AS%20%3FexistsPopEstim%20%29%0D%0A%09BIND%20%28IF%28%3FexistsPopEstim%20%2C%20%22ok%22%2C%20%22no%22%29%20AS%20%3FusedExPop%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) -- running 8.0 (2018 release), but doesn't have
  complete DBpedia dataset loaded.

That said, I can [recreate your problem](http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%20%3Furi%20%20%3FpopEstimate%20%3FexistsPopEstim%20%3FusedExPop%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%3E%20%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%09%3Furi%20%20a%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FPlace%3E.%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%7B%3Furi%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22France%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09UNION%20%7B%3Furi%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Br%C3%A9sil%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09UNION%20%7B%3Furi%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Am%C3%A9rique%22%40fr%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09OPTIONAL%20%7B%3Furi%20dbo%3ApopulationEstimate%20%3FpopEstimate%20.%7D%09%0D%0A%09BIND%20%28exists%7B%3Furi%20dbo%3ApopulationEstimate%20%3FpopEstimate%7D%20AS%20%3FexistsPopEstim%20%29%0D%0A%09BIND%20%28IF%28%3FexistsPopEstim%20%2C%20%22ok%22%2C%20%22no%22%29%20AS%20%3FusedExPop%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) via our LOD Cloud Cache instance. Thus, I suggest:

1. Upgrade on your part to one of the 2017 releases used in my examples above
2. We revisit our Cluster Edition which is running behind the LOD Cloud instance that I used to recreate your problem.

Comment: Currently added FROM CLAUSE reveals the problem i.e., commenting out the FROM CLAUSE is a temporary workaround.

Comment: As @AKSW demonstrates with another example, this problem occurs even on the current DBPedia End Point.

Comment: @Niii Kingsley already said that the problem can be recreated. The workaround is to remove the `FROM` clause, i.e. don't use a default graph.

Comment: With or without the FROM clause and with or without the default graph, the result is the same to me.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a virtuoso datatype issue as @Kingsley said, see: https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/693

Comment: Yes, ultimately this an issue originating from the underlying SQL Core (upon which SPARQL is implemented). 

Proof:
SELECT CASE WHEN (COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM DB.DBA.SYS_USERS WHERE U_NAME=''), 0)) THEN ( 'ok' ) ELSE ( 'no' ) end;

returns "ok" 

whereas 

SELECT COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM DB.DBA.SYS_USERS WHERE U_NAME=''), 0) 

Returns 0.